# Save type of reference to Firestore but get a string of [object object]

Tags: javascript, react-native, object, reference, google-cloud-firestore

I have a field in Firestore that has a reference as the value `current_recipient: Users/uid/recipients/1574404390193`.[image]

The frontend fetch the reference from this and tries to put a copy into a different document, but instead of the reference, I got `current_recipient: [object object]`

[image]

Here is the code

```
const curRecipientRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Users').doc(uid)
    curRecipientRef.get()
        .then( doc => {
            let data = doc.data()

            let ref = data.current_recipient

             let orderRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Users').doc(uid).collection( 'order_history').doc( orderId )
             orderRef.set({
                 recipientRef: ref,
              })

        })
        .catch( err => console.log(err) )
```

All I want is making a copy of the reference and save it somewhere else.

Comment: In one place you use `firebase.firestore()` to build the reference.  In another place you use `db`.  Is there an important difference between the two?

Comment: @DougStevenson My mistake, they should be the same.

Comment: I would expect this to work.  Try also filing a bug on GitHub and be sure to explain thoroughly how to duplicate this behavior.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk

Comment: @DougStevenson The 'ref' in this case is an object, I think the code somehow treats it as and regular object, not a firestore reference.

Comment: Right, I understand the problem here.  It might be a bug in the SDK, which is why I'm pointing you to the place to file it.

Comment: @DougStevenson Will definitely do that, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problem with data() as well recently and it appeared that it works fine. I just made a mistake and added toString. I dont see this problem in your code, but it would be something like:

```
let ref = data.current_recipient.toString()
```

Than the result was exectly the same. Maybe in your original code you have processed this ref value a little bit more and used something like this as well. Hope it will help!